# Question about convergence of sequences defined by infinite sums

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

This is not a homework problem, but arose naturally in a project I'm working on.

Let $x_{n}^{k}$ be a collection of integer valued sequences satisfying:

- $x_{n}^{k} \geq 0$ for all $n,k \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a_{n}:= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \frac{x_{n}^{k}}{n}$

Now define $b_{n} := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{n}^{k}}{n}$. Does $b_{n}$ necessarily converge?

Note that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_{n}^{k}$ is zero for all but finitely many indices $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further restrictions, you can play with 'disperse' rows and 'concentrated' rows to create a counter-example.

Indeed, pick $(x_n^k)$ as follows:

$$ x_n^k = \begin{cases} 2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{ k \leq \sqrt{n} \}}, & \text{$n$ is a square} \\
n \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{k = 1\}}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Then

$$ a_n = \begin{cases}
1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, & \text{$n$ is a square} \\
1, & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
b_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}, & \text{$n$ is a square} \\
1, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} $$

So we have $a_n \to 1$ while $(b_n)$ does not converge.